# Excel macro to copy and paste data from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I am trying to Search for a value in a column and copy row  from Sheet1 and creating new sheet as MySheet and pasting that particular row .But I am getting run time error while pasting data in  MySheet.Any suggestions please.

Data Input I am trying :

ID  name    price  units  desc

1   ikura       10     4      Mail Box

2   test        11     14     xxxx

3   test        11     14     yyyy

4   test        11     14     Mail Box

```
 Sub SearchForString()

        Dim LSearchRow As Integer
        Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

        On Error GoTo Err_Execute

        'Start search in row 4
        LSearchRow = 4

        'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
        LCopyToRow = 2

    Worksheets.Add (After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MySheet"
        While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

            'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
            If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then

                'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
                Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
                Selection.Copy

                'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
                Sheets("MySheet").Select
                Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

                'Move counter to next row
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

                'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select

            End If

            LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

        Wend

        'Position on cell A3
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A3").Select

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

        Exit Sub

    Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."

    End Sub
```

Regards,

Raju

Comment: What's the error? The line `Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MySheet"` runs fine here... (Excel 2007).

Comment: @Tiago:giving run time error in my machine at the time of pasting data in MySheet,It is able to create worksheet but not pasting data.

Comment: What is the **exact** runtime error message? "giving runtime error in my machine" doesn't help if we can't see your machine. Remember we only have the information you provide, as most of us don't read minds. If you don't tell us, we don't know and can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simplified version:

```
Sub CopyData()

    '// Turn off screen updating for cosmetics
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MySheet"

    '// Change this to your sheet you are copying from
    With Sheet1
        '// Filter all rows with Mail Box
        .Range("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mail Box", Operator:=xlAnd
        '// Copy all rows except header
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(2, 1)
        '// Remove the autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
     End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

End Sub
```

Comment: The code compiles fine for me.  Have you changed the "With Sheet1" to "With Worksheets("YourSheetName")?  It should be the name of the worksheet you are copying from.

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

- Stop using .Select and .Activate when they're not needed, they're the
  devil's methods.  Deal with range/worksheet objects directly.
- Change your row counters from intergers to longs just in case.
- Explicitly declaring which worksheet you're working with can save yourself from odd bugs/errors.  If you don't like the typing use a worksheet object.
- Your error handler should always output       err.Number and
  err.Description.  If you'd done that from the       beginning you
  probably wouldn't have had to post this question.
- Range.Copy has a destination argument.  Use it instead of Range.Paste
  to save some potential headaches.

Here's some simplified code, see if it works:

```
Sub SearchForString()
Dim LSearchRow As Long
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim wksInput As Worksheet
Dim wksOutput As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Create a new sheet output to and store a reference to it
'in the wksOutput variable
Set wksOutput = Worksheets.Add(AFter:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
wksOutput.Name = "MySheet"

'The wksInput variable will hold a reference to the worksheet
'that needs to be searched
Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2
'Loop through all the rows that contain data in the worksheet
'Start search in row 4
For LSearchRow = 4 To wksInput.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to wksOutput
    If wksInput.Cells(LSearchRow, 5) = "Mail Box" Then
        'One line copy/paste
        wksInput.Rows(LSearchRow).Copy wksOutput.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1)
        'Increment the output row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
    End If
Next LSearchRow

With wksInput
    .Activate
    .Range("A3").Select
End With



   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred. Number: " & Err.Number & " Description: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,But Got error  " An error occurred. Number:9 Description :Out of range"

Comment: Change "Sheet2" in the line Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") to whatever worksheet name that you're copying FROM.

Comment: After I change this line to Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1,It is copying only one occurence of "Mail Box" in Mysheet.But Sheet1 has 5 occurences of Mail Box.So here i have to Search "Mail Box" in D column.If it finds any Cell with "Mail Box" in D column .It should copy entire row to Mysheet.

Comment: Thanks,YOur explaination helped me lot