# Copy and replace excel data range rows one by one with pause in between copy operations

Tags: vba, excel

I have search this website, however I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Sorry, I am new to macro in excel, so I dont really know how I need to write a macro.

Let me explain my problem;

I have 2 worksheet;

- Worksheet 1
- Worksheet 2

What I want to do is:

1. Copy and paste `row 1` from `worksheet 1` to `worksheet 2`, save the excel file and wait. Then copy `row 2` from `worksheet 1` to same row in `worksheet 2` **replacing** the value.
2. Continue until rows in `worksheet 1`  (160 rows ) are all copy and pasted to `worksheet 2`.

However, the point is that I want to have time to have some time in between the copying of rows to do some other processing. I want to be able to click on a button (lets say NEXT button) and have it **only then** replace the next value.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I really appreciate your kind consideration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel macro to copy and paste data from one worksheet to another worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505198/excel-macro-to-copy-and-paste-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another-worksheet)

Comment: reformatted question and title to clarify important requirement

Answer (score 0):

when you call the save-dialog the macro will wait for your input

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

to make sure there is the stop command that you can set to pause for a defined time of seconds

```
Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:01#)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would it be possible to give me the full code. I actually want to save the excel file myself , and then I click on a button to copy and replace the next row. and this repeats unit all rows in worksheet 1 have copy and replaced

Comment: just use the macro recorder and do the steps in Excel to get an idea how to write VBA, then adjust the code to what you need.